# CriteriaBuilder search in 2 table get performance issue

Tags: java

I try to search a list keyword on 2 different table by CriteriaBuilder and get performance issue on line 26.
Can someone help me to improve this.

```
public static Specification<TrainingBatchVolunteerDetails> filterVolunteers(final TrainingVolunteerForm form) {
    return new Specification<TrainingBatchVolunteerDetails>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<TrainingBatchVolunteerDetails> root,
                CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            ....

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            Join<TrainingBatchVolunteerDetails, TrainingBatches> batches  = root.join("batches");
            Join<TrainingBatches, Training> training  = batches.join("training");
            training.join("trainingVolunteerDetails").join("eventBaseProfile");

            Join<TrainingBatches, EventBaseProfile> eventBaseProfile  = root.join("eventBaseProfile");
            Join<EventBaseProfile, BaseProfile> baseProfile  = eventBaseProfile.join("baseProfile");
            Join<CtExtendProfile, BaseProfile> ctExtendProfile = null;

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(form.getNricName())) {
                ...

                ctExtendProfile  = baseProfile.join("ctExtendProfile", JoinType.LEFT);
                List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();

                ...

                predicates.add(cb.or(
                    baseProfile.<String>get("identifierId").in(keywords),
                    ctExtendProfile.<String>get("birthCertificate").in(keywords)
                ));
            }

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: which line is line 26? And did you index the key rows on your DB?

Comment: Hi Arcans,
I indexed the key row. 
the line performance is 
predicates.add(cb.or(
           baseProfile.<String>get("identifierId").in(keywords),
           ctExtendProfile.<String>get("birthCertificate").in(keywords)
));

Comment: How big is your list of keywords? And did you index both of the 'identifierId' and 'birthCertificate' columns?

Comment: hi Matt, yes i did and the list keywords just about 2-3 element.
there are over 65k row data on each table. It alway take more than 60s when I get the generated query and run directly on mysql.